# Trigger a websocket from outside via PHP to send a message to clients

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, ratchet

my goal is to somehow trigger a secure ratchet websocket, where my clients have logged in via javascript, to send an update message to them.
My secure ratchet websocket is already working fine, as well as the wss connection via javascript, the clients can connect and disconnect from the websocket.

Websocket (PHP):

```
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use socket\secure\IoSecureServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use socket\http\WebHttpServer;

$http_server = IoSecureServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new WebHttpServer()
        )
    ),
    8091,
    "0.0.0.0",
    array(
        "local_cert" => "path/to/my/cert",
        "local_pk" => "path/to/my/key",
        "allow_self_signed" => true,
        "verify_peer" => false
    )
);

$http_server->run();
```

Client (JS):

```
let web_socket = new WebSocket("wss://domainname.de:8091");

            web_socket.onopen = function () {
                //do some stuff
                console.log("Connected to websocket");
            }

            web_socket.onclose = function () {
                //do some stuff
                console.warn("Connection closed");
            }

            web_socket.onerror = function () {
                //do some stuff
                web_socket.close();
            }

            web_socket.onmessage = function (ev) {
                //do some stuff
            }
```

Idea:
Now I was wondering how I could trigger this ratchet websocket:

**My idea:**
Through a connector I send a message to the socket, it recognizes that it was sent from the same device and accepts the content, evaluates it and sends a message with new information to all clients.

Problem:
I do not manage to reach the socket with a connector. The best attempt so far was the following:

```
$contextOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

$fp =stream_socket_client("ssl://domainname.de:8091",$errstr,$errno,30,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,$context);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: domainname.de\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nSec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==\r\n\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
}
```

So i get the following output:

```
[2022-07-02 12:29:20]  (68) connected to the server
[2022-07-02 12:29:20] 68 disconnected from the server
```

It should be noted that the ratchet server cannot determine an IP address.

I would like to know how I can get the IP address to be recognized and still be able to send a message?

***Or is there another way to tell a ratchet websocket: now you have to send out a message?***

Thanks a lot for your support!